# How to call XML layout dynamically?

Tags: android, layout, dynamically-generated

Here is my XML file I want to call dynamically in my activity .class

```
 <Tablerow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Location"
            android:background="#ff6600"

            />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/Access"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Accesss"
            android:background="#ffffff"
             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/Sel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Sell"
            android:background="#00ff00"
            />

    </TableRow>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button5"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
        android:text="Button" />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by call dynamically ? setContentView() ?

Comment: setContentView(); and pass the layout

Comment: "call dynamically" you say?

Comment: I'm new to android, i want change the values like size,alignment of buttons dynamically from my activity.java file..

Comment: you can do that programatically, not required to call the layout dynamically. Use java code to modify the size, aligments etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look to this great example
http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/05/resize-button-programmatically-using.html
You can use the java code to programatically change the size and aligment of the buttons. Something like that

```
button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10, 100));
```